# transposing database date value into datepicker field

Tags: javafx, datepicker

I am having difficulty with my code to convert the date value from the database into my form datepicker field.

this is the code I am using:

item.setValue(LocalDate.parse(row.get(11), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It's impossible to help you if you don't share the content of `row.get(11)`.

Comment: Hi @DVarga, the row.get(11) is coming from my ObservableList containing the array values from the database.

Comment: it prints out 2017-01-20 from the database as a string value

Comment: If `"2017-01-20".equals(row.get(11))` evaluates as `true`, it should be okay. What exception do you get?

Comment: @DVarga 
the error it prints is:
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Post the complete stack trace in the question, along with the output from `row.get(11)`.

Comment: this was human error - the DatePicker field name was misspelled.
sorry folks!